# How Do I Fix This SED Command to Find & Replace a String

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, debian

**Good-day,**

I'm working on a Bash script for Debian Jessie and in this line;

```
<param name="script-directory" value="$${base_dir}/scripts/?.lua"/>
```

I am trying to find **base_dir}/scripts** and replace it with **script_dir}** so that my new line will read as:

```
<param name="script-directory" value="$${script_dir}/?.lua"/>
```

This is what I have tried so far;

```
sed -rn '/s/base_dir}\/scripts/script_dir}/p' /etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/lua.conf.xml
```

which results in this error;

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unexpected `}'
```

I am confused as to how to resolve this and would appreciate some assistance please, thanks.

Comment: remove the initial `/`, it shouldn't be there

Comment: thanks, that seemed to clear the error.  but the file still didn't get changed.  It simply outputted the change to the terminal, so I changed the /p flag to /g but didn't change the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `sed` with an alternate delimiter to avoid escaping `/`:

```
sed 's~base_dir}/scripts~script_dir}~' /etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/lua.conf.xml
```

You don't need `-r` here (needed for extended regex)

Comment: Thanks, however, that just outputted the change to the terminal but didn't actually change the string in the file

Comment: To change file you can use: `sed -i '' 's~base_dir}/scripts~script_dir}~' /etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/lua.conf.xml`

Comment: sweet, that worked......but without the ' ' after the -i.  Any reason for the ticks?

Comment: Older sed versions like on OSX need an argument after `-i`  but gnu sed works with `sed -i 's~base_dir}/scripts~script_dir}~' /etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/lua.conf.xml` as well